# Datetimepicker javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo este datepicker, en el cual muestro las fechas bloqueadas segun la condicion de que esten aceptadas o no, intento filtrar ahora por un nuevo parametro, area_id.
Si el area_id de los datos es igual a la del usuario deben mostrarse las fechas en naranja y si aceptado es igual a 1 bloquearse y pintarse de rojo.

Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
var daysData = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;
var isArea = {{ Auth::user()->area_id }}
var newA = [];
for( j of daysData){
  let start = moment(j["start"]);
  let end   = moment(j["end"]);

  for (let m = moment(start); m.diff(end, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
    newA[m.format('DD/MM/YYYY')] = j;
  }
}

$('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({

isInvalidDate: function(date) {
    var valid = false ; // default css class
    let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
        if(newA[d].acept == 1 && newA[d].area_id == isArea){
            valid =  true;
        }
    }
    return valid;
},
isCustomDate: function(date) {

  var daySettings = 'day_green';
  let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
       daySettings = 'day_red';
           if(newA[d].acept == 0 && newA[d].area_id ==isArea){
            daySettings = 'day_orange';
           }
        }
  }
  return daySettings;
},
```

Pro me sigue pintando las fechas que no corresponden al area_id del usuario con lo cual me tiene un poco frustrado. Agradeceria una manita.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: ¿La consola te da algún error de javascript? Aquí falta un punto y coma al final aunque puede que no haga falta (si estás usando algún transpilador de javascript): var isArea = {{ Auth::user()->area_id }}

Comment: Uso el framework de laravel, con lo que el area_id me lo coje correctamente ya que hice un console.log y me pinta el area_id del usuario correctamente, pero en la condicion debe ser que no estoy comparando como debo

Comment: Pues prueba a poner console.log(newA[d].area_id); console.log(isArea); console.log(newA[d].area_id == isArea); Para ver qué valores saca

Comment: Lo he probado y newA[d].area_id no me muestra nada por consola sin embargo en el json puedes ver los datos perfectamente, este es el output con console lod de daysData: {area_id: 2, title: "asd", start: "2018-08-30", end: "2018-08-31", acept: 0} y este el output de newA : {area_id: 2, title: "asd", start: "2018-08-12", end: "2018-08-12", acept: 0} sera por ponerle el [d]?

Comment: Claro, newA[d] sería si fuera un array pero es un objeto

Comment: Se supone que es un array... ya me estoy liando un poco x)

Comment: Si  newA es igual a {area_id: 2, title: "asd", start: "2018-08-12", end: "2018-08-12", acept: 0} en Javascript, eso es un objeto. Si fuera un array sería del estilo [1, 2, 3] o [{area_id: 2, title: "", ...}, {}]

Comment: oye perdoname la ignorancia pero esto es correcto `Auth::user()->area_id` nunca habia visto esta manera de llamar metodos en JS

Comment: Estoy trabajando con el framework de laravel, el cual te permite realizar ese tipo de llamadas, es php incrustado.

Answer (score 1):

Resuelto, he realizado el filtro directamente en php, con lo cual, cuando realizo la consulta a la base de datos ya filtro directamente por el area_id, sin necesidad de modificar nada en javascript ya que traigo los datos correctos al front.

Adjunto la consulta:

```
$data =  \DB::table('vacations')->select('*')
        ->join('users','users.id','=','vacations.user_id')
        ->where(['vacations.area_id' => $fil])
        ->get();

    return $data;
```